# How to connect socks5 proxy in fedora 39?

Tags: fedora, ip, socks5-proxy

I recently switched from Windows to Fedora, and I'm used to using "Proxifier" on Windows to connect to a proxy server effortlessly.
Now, I've got this socks5 IP, port, username, and password that I want to use system-wide.
I tried some tools, but they're either not working or too complicated for me.

Can you suggest something or walk me through the steps?
Also, I'd like to know how to easily turn the proxy on or off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps to set up the proxy system-wide.

#### Setting Up the Proxy

1. **Edit the `/etc/environment` File**:

   - Open a terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/environment`.
   - Add the following lines to the file, replacing `your_proxy_ip`, `your_proxy_port`, `your_username`, and `your_password` with your actual proxy details:

     ```
     http_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"
     https_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"
     ftp_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"
     no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"
     ```
   - Save the file and exit the editor.
2. **Apply the Changes**:

   - To apply the changes, you can either log out and log back in, or you can source the environment file by running `source /etc/environment` in the terminal.

#### Setting Up a Script to Toggle the Proxy

1. **Create a Toggle Script**:

   - Create a new script file, for example, `toggle_proxy.sh`, by running `nano ~/toggle_proxy.sh`.
   - Add the following content to the script:

     ```bash
     #!/bin/bash

     if grep -q "http_proxy" /etc/environment; then
         sed -i '/http_proxy/d' /etc/environment
         sed -i '/https_proxy/d' /etc/environment
         sed -i '/ftp_proxy/d' /etc/environment
         sed -i '/no_proxy/d' /etc/environment
         echo "Proxy disabled."
     else
         echo 'http_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
         echo 'https_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
         echo 'ftp_proxy="socks5://your_username:your_password@your_proxy_ip:your_proxy_port"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
         echo 'no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"' | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
         echo "Proxy enabled."
     fi
     ```
   - Replace `your_username`, `your_password`, `your_proxy_ip`, and `your_proxy_port` with your actual proxy details.
   - Save the file and exit the editor.
   - Make the script executable by running `chmod +x ~/toggle_proxy.sh`.
2. **Toggle the Proxy**:

   - To enable or disable the proxy, simply run `./toggle_proxy.sh` in the terminal.

#### Note

- The `/etc/environment` file is a system-wide configuration file that sets environment variables. Changes made here will affect all users on the system.
- The toggle script checks if the proxy settings are present in `/etc/environment`. If they are, it removes them, effectively disabling the proxy. If they are not present, it adds them, enabling the proxy.
- Remember to replace `your_username`, `your_password`, `your_proxy_ip`, and `your_proxy_port` with your actual SOCKS5 proxy details.